# Unable to see a rectangle in my form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

Here's my code:

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Hardest_Game
{
    class MainWindow : Form
    {
        private SolidBrush _brush;
        private Graphics _graphics;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            // Set MainWindow's properties
            this.Text = "World's Hardest Game";
            this.Size = new Size(640, 480);
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = this.MinimizeBox = false;

            // Declare graphics
            _brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            _graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            _graphics.FillRectangle(_brush, new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hardest_Game
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainWindow());
        }
    }
}
```

Yet nothing gets drawn on the form when I run it?

Comment: As far as I remember you have to redraw everything each time the [window invalidates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, it is doubtful that one-time painting inside the constructor will persist (after it there will happen at least one invalidation for sure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to paint your rectangle in constructor.

Frankly, it is not the best place to paint something on your form due to many reasons. For example, form is not actually visible at this moment.

Instead you have to move all of your painting code into `OnPaint` method override:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnPaint(e);
     e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_brush, new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100));
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! :) Why do you use `protected` here instead of `public` or `private`?

Comment: @SkamahOne Because [`Control.OnPaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a protected virtual method which you can override, and you are not allowed to change the access modifiers on a method you override.

Comment: Just because it is override of protected `Control.OnPaint` method. Alternatively you can handle `Paint` event instead of usage method override. And yes - I can't imagine why painting method ever should be public. ;)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Also, don't use a separate graphics object. Use `e.Graphics` to draw in `OnPaint ` method.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel reasonable note, thank you. Missed this point.

Comment: And imo using the OnPaint instead of the Paint event makes sense if and only if you plan on inheriting the Form.